# Delete records using Import/upload

Tags: netsuite

I just want to ask if there's any way to Delete records using import/Upload?

I want to Delete This Address(showing image below REDBOX) which having null value Under VENDOR setup.

https://preview.redd.it/86q8tmv7cr271.png?width=1880&format=png&auto=webp&s=d051068c3b01781b575ac7f93e44f49f52c89d16

And I have Excel file that have all records of NULL value of address.
https://preview.redd.it/k48mnbsmcr271.png?width=1920&format=png&auto=webp&s=f79a68613a680cf11400f3e7b8b19c6077571d84

I want to delete them using IMPORT or Upload ?, Please Teach me how to do it.
Is it possible to delete them by using this method ?

Please Help.

Comment: Addresses are a sublist. If you import vendor + ids of the addresses you want to keep then the rest will get deleted as long as the import option OVERWRITE SUBLISTS is checked. As always test with a small number of records in sandbox then production first.

Comment: Wow this is great Brian, Its working. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, Brian Please Put this into an Answer, So I can resolved the question